# When import icon fonts file got error

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, stylus

In my project, I want to use icon font.
This is  some content of  icon.styl:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'sell-icon';
 src:  url('../fonts/sell-icon.eot?o23a15');
 src:  url('../fonts/sell-icon.eot?o23a15#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/sell-icon.ttf?o23a15') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/sell-icon.woff?o23a15') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/sell-icon.svg?o23a15#sell-icon') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
 }
```

But unlucky, I have got 4 errors when compiling:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                        
 11:22:32

 These relative modules were not found:

* ../fonts/sell-icon.eot?o23a15 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-12835cef","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/header/header.vue
* ../fonts/sell-icon.svg?o23a15 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-12835cef","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/header/header.vue
* ../fonts/sell-icon.ttf?o23a15 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-12835cef","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/header/header.vue
* ../fonts/sell-icon.woff?o23a15 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-12835cef","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/header/header.vue
```

I have installed stylus-loader and css-loader:

```
npm install stylus stylus-loader --save-dev
npm install stylus css-loader --save-dev
```

And  fonts and stylus are in the same directory. files of sell-icon.* are in fonts directory. icon.styl is in stylus directory.

Who can help me?

Comment: Try to remove `../` from paths.

Comment: @KoshVery, I have tested for removing ../ from paths.  It fails again

Comment: @KoshVery, I solved this problem with absolute path